Merge local Time and date to make DATE in UTC in javascript
I am making a calendar app and getting a start date for an event to start from and shift start time, endtime and name. and pick value of time locally.
let formattedStartDate
    if (mergedFormData.datePicker) {
      const formDate = new Date(mergedFormData.datePicker);
      formattedStartDate = formDate.toISOString();
    }

In formattedStartDate, i pick the value and formate into the UTC Date. Secondly, I pick the shift values such as below and that is the value of
{
    "name": "Morning",
    "startTime": "22:00",
    "endTime": "23:00"
}

const zonedShifts = activeTabIndex === 0 ? this.convertShiftsToZonedTime(mergedFormData.shifts, formattedStartDate): [];

mergedFormDate.shifts are the json object given above.
Now , the date that we selected such as July31st, it is converted into UTC formate and it becomes
startTime: "2024-08-02T19:00:00.000Z
and now I want to make the shiftStartTime/endtime in the formate of UTC. For example, shift will become
{
    "name": "Morning",
    "startTime": "2024-08-02T17:00:00.000Z",
    "endTime": "2024-08-02T18:00:00.000Z"
}

And I am in karachi / pakistan and it should handle the timezone changes as well.
I have tried a couple of methods as well such as
convertShiftsToZonedTime(shifts, eventStartDate) {
    const eventDate = new Date(eventStartDate);

    const day = String(eventDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    const month = String(eventDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    const year = eventDate.getFullYear();

    const localDateString = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    console.log("localDateString", localDateString);

  
    return shifts.map(shift => {
      const shiftStart = new Date(`${localDateString}T${shift.startTime}:00`);
      console.log("here is the shift start", shiftStart)
      const shiftEnd = new Date(`${localDateString}T${shift.endTime}:00`);
  
      return {
        ...shift,
        startTime: shiftStart.toISOString(),
        endTime: shiftEnd.toISOString()
      };
    });
  }

but it changes the date if I pick the values above 12 as it is converting to utc so time and date is also changed. How can i solve this issue.

Javascript will always apply the user's timezone offset to the date you build manually.
To fix it, you must apply the offset to your date.
You can see several answers of this question, here's a possible implementation from top answer:
return shifts.map(shift => {
    const shiftStart = new Date(`${localDateString}T${shift.startTime}:00`);

    // Insert the following lines for shiftStart, do the same for shiftEnd
    const hoursDiff = shiftStart.getHours() - shiftStart.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
    const minutesDiff = (shift.getHours() - shiftStart.getTimezoneOffset()) % 60;
    shiftStart.setHours(hoursDiff);
    shiftStart.setMinutes(minutesDiff);

Note that some timezone offset have minutes like +01:30
Also, you must compute the offset from a specific date because the offset can change depending on the month (summer/winter time).

If the intention is to treat the timestamp as UTC, then appending a Z will do: new Date(\${localDateString}T${startTime}Z`)`. There is no need to append seconds, they can be omitted.

(shift.getHours() - shiftStart.getTimezoneOffset()) % 60 should probably be (shift.getMinutes() - shiftStart.getTimezoneOffset()) % 60. You can also do shiftStart.setHours(hoursDiff, minutesDiff). ;-)
